# Ctypes to get back data from python with struct and char*

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I need to populate a struct from python to C and I don't know how allocate the memory to char pointers if I unkown the sizes returned.

file.c

```
typedef struct _CONFIG 
{
    int             id          ;
    char            *name       ;
} CONFIG, *PCONFIG;

config = malloc(sizeof(CONFIG));
getConfig(config);

int getConfig(PCONFIG config)
{
    PyObject *PyGetConfig;
    pargs = PyTuple_Pack(1
        , PyLong_FromVoidPtr(config)
        );
    if (PyCallable_Check(PyGetConfig)) {
        ppresult = PyObject_CallObject(PyGetConfig, pargs);
        PyErr_Print();
    } else {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    printf("Result getConfig is %d\n",PyInt_AsLong(ppresult));
    return PyInt_AsLong(ppresult);
}
```

file.py

```
class _PyConfig(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('id',                      ctypes.c_int),
        ('name',                    ctypes.c_char_p)
    ]

def getConfig   (config):
    try:
        co = _PyConfig.from_address(config)
    except Exception as e:
        print( "Error creating config object -> Error Description: " + str(e))
        return -1
    co.id   = dict_Config['id']
    co.name = dict_Config['name']
```

How I can allocating memory for `char *name`?

Comment: co.name = ctypes.c_char_p(dict_Config['name'])   should work for a bytes object. If the parameter is a string an encoding is necessary first.

Comment: None of the code snippets compiles (one can spot that by the naked eye). [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).